# How to fetch from Node Js once

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, fetch-api

I want to trim a video if it is longer than 10 minutes and fetch the trimmed video but it happens to work in an infinite loop, which is what i am trying to stop. i just dont know how

1. Initially, the video processing is triggered when a video longer than 10 minutes is selected.
2. While the video processing is ongoing, the user interface (UI) code continues to execute, and if the video selection remains the same, it might trigger the processing again
3. This leads to multiple instances of FFmpeg processing the same video file concurrently, creating the infinite loop behavior.

```
function previewReels(event) {
                const videos = document.getElementById('videos').files;
                const previewItems = document.querySelector('.preview-items');
                const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');

                // Display videos
                for (let i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
                    // const videoElement = document.createElement('video');
                    // videoElement.controls = true;
                    // videoElement.autoplay = true;
                    const previewItem = document.createElement('div');
                    previewItem.className = 'preview-item';
                    previewItems.appendChild(previewItem);

                    const formData = new FormData();

                    const videoInput = document.getElementById('videos');

                    if (videoInput.files.length > 0) {
                        const videoFile = videoInput.files[0];
                        console.log('VideoFile:', videoFile);
                        console.log('Uploaded file mimetype:', videoFile.type);

                        formData.append('Video', videoFile);

                        const videoElement = document.createElement('video');
                        videoElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(videoFile);

                        videoElement.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
                            const videoDuration = videoElement.duration;
                            const videoinmins = videoDuration / 60;
                            console.log('Video Duration:', videoinmins);

                            if (videoDuration > 600) {
                                videoElement.style.display = "none";
                                const loader = document.createElement('img');
                                loader.src = 'icons/internet.gif';
                                loader.classList.add('loader');
                                previewItems.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                                previewItem.appendChild(loader);

                                fetch('http://localhost:8888/trimVideo', {
                                        method: 'POST',
                                        body: formData,
                                    })
                                    .then((response) => {
                                        if (!response.ok) {
                                            throw new Error('Error fetching trimmed video data.');
                                        }
                                        return response.blob(); // Get the video data as a Blob
                                    })
                                    .then((videoBlob) => {
                                        previewItem.removeChild(loader);
                                        videoElement.style.display = "block";
                                        loader.style.display = "none";
                                        buttons.style.display = "block";
                                        const trimmedVideoURL = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
                                        videoElement.src = trimmedVideoURL;
                                        previewItem.appendChild(videoElement);
                                        previewItem.style.backgroundColor = "#333";
                                    })
                                    .catch((error) => {
                                        console.error(error);
                                    });
                            } else {
                                videoElement.controls = true;
                                buttons.style.display = "block";
                                previewItems.style.backgroundColor = "#333";
                                previewItem.appendChild(videoElement);
                            }
                        });
            }

            // Listen for file selection change
            document.getElementById('videos').addEventListener('change', previewReels);
```

and for this server side

```
app.post("/trimVideo", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Received a POST request to /trim-video");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  // Access the video file and log its details
  const videoFile = req.files.Video;
  console.log("Received video file:", videoFile);
  console.log(" - Name:", videoFile.name);
  console.log(" - Type:", videoFile.mimetype);
  console.log(" - Size:", videoFile.size, "bytes");
  console.log(" - Data length:", videoFile.data.length);

  if (!req.files || !req.files.Video) {
    console.log("not working");
    return res.status(400).send("No video file uploaded.");
  }

  console.log("started");

  if (videoFile.mimetype.startsWith("video/")) {
    const progressFilePath = 'progress.txt';
    fs.writeFileSync(videoFile.name, videoFile.data);
    const inputFormat = videoFile.name.split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
    console.log("Trimming video...");
    console.log(inputFormat);
    console.log(videoFile.data);
    ffmpeg()
      .input(videoFile.name)
      .inputFormat(inputFormat)
      .outputOptions("-t 600")
      .outputFormat("ismv")
      .on("end", () => {
        console.log("Video trimming completed.");

        // Read the trimmed video data from the temporary file
        const trimmedVideoBuffer = fs.readFileSync(videoFile.name);

        // Delete the temporary file
        fs.unlinkSync(videoFile.name);

        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "Video/ismv");
        res.setHeader("Content-Length", trimmedVideoBuffer.length);
        res.send(trimmedVideoBuffer);
      })
      .on("error", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.error("Error trimming video:", err);
        console.error("FFmpeg stdout:", stdout);
        console.error("FFmpeg stderr:", stderr);
        res.status(500).send(`Error trimming the video: ${err.message}`);
      })
      .on("progress", (progress) => {
        console.log("trimming-progress", progress);
      })
      .save(progressFilePath);
  } else {
    res.status(400).send("Invalid video file format.");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple issues.

- First of all, maybe just disable the button while process in on-going? It might be not the case, but it's hard to understand without more details.
- Verify the `previewReels` is called once. I can't tell for sure without seeing more code, but it feels like it could be called multiple times.
- If the `previewReels` is triggered by user interaction with some range input or slider (or other) make sure you use some debouncing strategy to avoid "happy-trigger" processing.
- Consider adding cancel feature if the cutting process takes a while and you expect . The `ffmpeg` wrapper might already allow it somehow (or maybe just kill the process and ignore error?). You would have to also keep track of promises on UI side too to properly ignore them failing.

Comment: I noticed from the console log that the main issue was with the loadedmetadata

it kept repeating everything inside the function
that was why it was feeling like the fetch was working multiple times